# VB.NET How to detect a collision in a maze

Tags: .net, vb.net, collision

I'm building a maze application in visual basic. The game relies on two variables, X and Y which are integers. There's a timer which basically invalidates the whole form for a redraw. Now my question is, that there are various squares and rectangles dotted around the form. How would I create a handler, or something as such to detect if the square that the form draws is touching these objects?

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Const W As Integer = 35 'Width
    Const H As Integer = 35 'Height

    Dim X As Integer
    Dim Y As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        'Handles if a key is pressed
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Up
                Y -= 2
            Case Keys.Down
                Y += 2
            Case Keys.Left
                X -= 2
            Case Keys.Right
                X += 2

            Case Keys.Escape
                Me.Close()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Maze"
        TmrRedraw.Start()
        MsgBox("Press ESC to quit")
        Cursor.Position = Me.Location
    End Sub

    Private Sub TmrRedraw_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TmrRedraw.Tick
        If CollisionDetect() = False Then
            Me.Invalidate()
            CheckForWin()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Function CollisionDetect()
        Dim Collision As Boolean = False

        'Here is where the problem lies 


        Return Collision
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, X, Y, W, H)

    End Sub

    Private Sub CheckForWin()
        Dim WinSqX As Integer = WinSquare.Location.X
        Dim WinSqY As Integer = WinSquare.Location.Y

        If X = WinSqX And Y = WinSqY Then

            TmrRedraw.Stop()
            MsgBox("Congratulations! You won!")
            Me.Close()
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

Oh yes - the player must use the arrow keys to change the X and Y, and when it redraws, it will move.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the need for the timer in your example since you just need to invalidate whenever the user is pressing the keyboard.

For object collision, you would need a list of objects that have their rectangle coordinates, and then just test for an intersection:

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim block As New Rectangle(0, 0, 35, 35)  
  Dim listOfThings As New List(Of Rectangle)

  Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True

    listOfThings.Add(New Rectangle(40, 40, 35, 35))
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode
      Case Keys.Up
        MoveBlock(0, -2)
      Case Keys.Down
        MoveBlock(0, 2)
      Case Keys.Left
        MoveBlock(-2, 0)
      Case Keys.Right
        MoveBlock(2, 0)
      Case Keys.Escape
        Me.Close()
    End Select
  End Sub

  Private Sub MoveBlock(ByVal moveX As Integer, ByVal moveY As Integer)
    block.X += moveX
    block.Y += moveY

    For Each r As Rectangle In listOfThings
      If r.IntersectsWith(block) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Game Over")
      End If
    Next

    Me.Invalidate()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White)

    For Each r As Rectangle In listOfThings
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, r)
    Next

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, block)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So: Block is the player's unit here, Listofthings is a list containing all of the rectangles on the  board.
1 question: What is Public Sub New() - is this meant to be Form1_Load?

Comment: @Azerty560 Yes, it' basically your x, y, w, h variables as a simple rectangle object.

Comment: Do I need to manually populate the array listofthings with all the rectangles? (Does this mean I actually need absolutely nothing on the form?) 
Thanks for the answer though =)

Comment: @Azerty560 In my example, no you wouldn't.  If you are using controls on the form, you would still need some kind of list or enumerate through your controls to get the location and size of your collidable controls to test for the intersection.